# Xampp not working after updating on mac os big sur 11.4

Tags: xampp

The error message keep poping up when click the start button... Im using a macbook air M1, MacOs Big Sur 11.4

cannot calculate MAC address: Using fd 9 for I/O notifications
hv_vm_create HV_ERROR (unspecified error)

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading from 8.0.8 to 7.3.29 / PHP 7.3.29, that should do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).